# Change calculator

Tags: c#

i have a tusk where i have been asked to write a program that calculate change to be given to a customer after a cash transaction, and determines the number of bank notes and coins in each denomination.

the user has to put in the cost of goods and the amount received from the customer.

I must have a class with a method that accepts decimal arguments, Cost and Chashreceived, plus integer arguments for: Hunderds, Fifties, Twenties, Tens, Fives, Twos, Ones, 50c, 10c, 5c, 2c and 1c.

i substract Cost from  and the Cashreceived and calculate the exact number of notes and coins required to be returned as change.

I have tried it but it become problematic when i have to put in the coins.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ChangeCalculator
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        clsCash Money = new clsCash();
        clsCash Paid = new clsCash();
        Console.WriteLine("What is the cost of the goods?");
        Money.Cost = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("How much was recived?");
        Paid.CashRecieved = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
        Money.GetChange(Money.Cost, Paid.CashRecieved);
        Console.Read();
    }
}

class clsCash
{


private decimal cost;
private decimal cashRecieved;
public decimal Cost
{
    get
    {
        return cost;
    }
    set
    {
        cost = value;
    }
}
public decimal CashRecieved
{
    get
    {
        return cashRecieved;
    }
    set
    {
        cashRecieved = value;
    }
}




public void GetChange(decimal Cost, decimal CashRecieved)
{

    decimal change = CashRecieved - Cost;
    int hundreds = 0;
    int fifty = 0;
    int twenty = 0;
    int ten = 0;
    int five = 0;
    int two = 0;
    int one = 0;
    int centsfifty = 0;
    int centsten = 0;
    int centsfive = 0;
    int centstwo = 0;
    int centsone = 0;
    do
   {

    if (change >= 100)
    {
         hundreds = (int)change / 100;
         change = (int)change % 100;
    } //while (change > 0);
    else if (change >= 50)
    {
        fifty = (int)change / 50;
        change = change % 50;
    }
    else if (change >= 20)
    {
        twenty = (int)change / 20;
        change = change % 20;
    }
    else if (change >= 10)
    {
        ten = (int)change / 10;
        change = change % 10;
    }
    else if (change >= 5)
    {
        five = (int)change / 5;
        change = change % 5;
    }
    else if (change >= 2)
    {
        two = (int)change / 2;
        change = change % 2;
    }

    else if (change >= 1)
    {
        one = (int)change / 1;
        change = change % 1;
    }
    else if (change > 1)
    {
        decimal fhu = change / 0.5m;
        centsfifty = (int)fhu;
        change = change % 0.5m;
        Console.WriteLine("YOUR CHANGE IS:");
    }

    } while (change >= 0);


    Console.WriteLine("YOUR CHANGE IS:");
    Console.WriteLine("---------------");
    Console.WriteLine("HUNDREDS RANDS \t:  {0}", hundreds);
    Console.WriteLine("FIFTY RANDS \t:  {0}", fifty);
    Console.WriteLine("TWENTY RANDS \t:  {0}", twenty);
    Console.WriteLine("TEN RANDS \t:  {0}", ten);
    Console.WriteLine("FIVE RANDS \t:  {0}", five);
    Console.WriteLine("TWO RANDS \t:  {0}", two);
    Console.WriteLine("ONE RANDS \t:  {0}", one);
    Console.WriteLine("50 CENTS \t:  {0}", centsfifty);

}
}
}
```

Comment: If you want an answer your are going to need to be more specific about the problem your having.

Comment: Shouldn't that last `else if` be `else if (change < 1)`? I think you have your sign flipped.

Comment: Advice - do not use prefixes like `cls` in your code. `Cash` is pretty enough for class name. IDE will tell you other information about type

Comment: You should really learn to create Classes for this ..actually sounds like you're being put to the test here on your job.. you need to clean up this code and break it down into manageable parts or pieces..

Comment: Is this homework / a programming assignment for school?

Answer (score 1):

There is a pattern you can use to get the amounts like this,

Here is a small example to get you started, you could probably wrap it up in a function or something, but it gives you an idea on where to start.

```
// number to find values from
int change = 254;

int _hundreds = 100;
int _fifty = 50;
int _twenty = 20;
int _ten = 10;
int _five = 5;
int _two = 2;
int _one = 1;

int hundreds = (int)(change / _hundreds);
int fifty = (int)((change % _hundreds) / _fifty);
int twenty = (int)(((change % _hundreds) % _fifty) / _twenty);
int ten = (int)((((change % _hundreds) % _fifty) % _twenty) / _ten);
int five = (int)(((((change % _hundreds) % _fifty) % _twenty) % _ten) / _five);
int two = (int)((((((change % _hundreds) % _fifty) % _twenty) % _ten) % _five) / _two);
int one = (int)(((((((change % _hundreds) % _fifty) % _twenty) % _ten) % _five) % _two) / _one);
```

Returns

```
hundreds = 2
fifty = 1
twenty = 0
ten = 0
five = 0
two = 2
one = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to help simplify your code and improve it's readability is to eliminate the conditionals and
nested arithmetic operations, which almost always make the code harder to understand.

I see int is being cast too many times, this probably means it's best to use int right from the start. Eventhough you declare the cost and cashreceived variables as decimal types they are both being cast to int.
Therefore it would be better to declare both of them as int from the beginning, this will help to ease on the casting.

you may do something like this

```
hundreds = change / 100;
change %= 100;

fifty = change / 50;
change %= 50;

ten = change / 10;
change %= 10;

five = change / 5;
change %= 5;

two = change / 2;
change %= 2;

one = change;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
     if (change >= 100)
     {
     hundreds = (int)change / 100;
     change = (int)change % 100;

     }
```

Try using

```
        if (change >= 100)
        {
            decimal rand = change / 100;
            hundred= (int)rand;
            change = change % 100;
        }


        if (change >= 50)
        {
            decimal rand = (int)change / 50;
            fifty = (int)rand;
            change = change % 50;
        }


        if (change >= 20)
        {
            decimal rand = change / 20;
            twenty = (int)rand;
            change = change % 20;
        }
```

I hope this helps.